# get all days and dates for the selected month of a year

Tags: php, date

how to get both days and dates for selected month of selected year and show in tables.
e-g:
i have tried so far.

```
<?php
$num_of_days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 9, 2003);
for( $i=1; $i<= $num_of_days; $i++)
    $dates[]= str_pad($i,2,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
/*echo "<pre>";
print_r($dates);
echo "</pre>";*/
?>
<table>
    <tr>
<?php
foreach($dates as $date){
    echo"<td>".$date."</td>";
}
?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

this executes for me this code.

```
<table>
    <tbody><tr>
<td>01</td><td>02</td><td>03</td><td>04</td><td>05</td><td>06</td><td>07</td><td>08</td><td>09</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td><td>21</td><td>22</td><td>23</td><td>24</td><td>25</td><td>26</td><td>27</td><td>28</td><td>29</td><td>30</td>    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

but i want another row below the dates row.
which should show day related to that date??

by day i mean :monday, tues, wed etc.
by date i mean : 1, 2, 3, 4 etc

so it would be like

```
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td>
<tr><td>Mon</td><td>Tues</td><td>Wed</td><td>Thursday</td>
```

I hope i could explain my self..

Comment: day related to that day stands for? Oo

Comment: i meant day realted to that date.. xD
e-g monday, tues, wed etc.

Comment: you can use maybe this command -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.jddayofweek.php

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `date('l')` to get the corresponding day name:

```
<?php
$date = '2003-09-01';
$end = '2003-09-' . date('t', strtotime($date)); //get end date of month
?>
<table>
    <tr>
    <?php while(strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end)) {
        $day_num = date('d', strtotime($date));
        $day_name = date('l', strtotime($date));
        $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
        echo "<td>$day_num <br/> $day_name</td>";
    }
    ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wouldn't day_num be an int between 1 and 31? Today in Julian is 2,457,004.

Comment: Thankyou. But it is not showing right day for that date..
i mean this month first date is starting from monday, but when i checked with your code, it started from tuesday ?

Comment: @SizzlingCode i revised this answer, actually my first idea was to use DateTime classes but theres an answer below like it, but this should work okay

Comment: Thankyou. Just Checked back your code again. and tested it with different months. result works perfectly great.. right day name for right date and for right month of the year. Many Thanks again..

Answer (score 10):

A different approach could be to use the DateTime object:

```
$aDates = array();
$oStart = new DateTime('2014-12-01');
$oEnd = clone $oStart;
$oEnd->add(new DateInterval("P1M"));

while ($oStart->getTimestamp() < $oEnd->getTimestamp()) {
    $aDates[] = $oStart->format('D d');
    $oStart->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
}
```

Then to print:

```
foreach ($aDates as $day) {
    echo $day;
}
```

For more information about the format parameters, you can refer to: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: How to print day and dates both together with this approach??? as i want them to display???

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this

```
$myYearMonth = '2003-09';

$start = new DateTime(date('Y-m-01', strtotime($myYearMonth)));
$end = new DateTime(date('Y-m-t', strtotime($myYearMonth)));

$diff = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$periodStart = new DatePeriod($start, $diff, $end);

foreach ( $periodStart as $dayDate ){
  echo '<td>'.$dayDate->format( "d\n" ).'</td><td>'.$dayDate->format( "l\n" ).'</td>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use the [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function as the date range is limited to 1970-2038 according to the PHP documentation :

> The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 GMT to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT. (These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed integer). However, before PHP 5.1.0 this range was limited from 01-01-1970 to 19-01-2038 on some systems (e.g. Windows).

Using the [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.datetime.php) class you can retrieve the information you need for a given month using the following function. This uses [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/datetime.format.php) to get the day name in English (no localization).

```
function getMonth($year, $month) {

    // this calculates the last day of the given month
    $last=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);

    $date=new DateTime();
    $res=Array();

    // iterates through days
    for ($day=1;$day<=$last;$day++) {
            $date->setDate($year, $month, $day);

            $res[$day]=$date->format("l");
    }
    return $res;
}
```

This will return an associated array like the following:

```
$res=getMonth(2015, 2);
print_r($res);


Array
(
[1] => Sunday
[2] => Monday
[3] => Tuesday
[4] => Wednesday
[5] => Thursday

[...]

)
```

To output the data in a two-row table, you can use the following code:

```
<?php
echo '<table><tr><td>'.implode('</td><td>', array_keys($res)).'</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>'.implode('</td><td>', $res).'</td></tr></table>';
```

As the `Datetime::format()` function does not support locales for translation, you can use an associative array to get the translation in another language.

Answer (score 3):

Full solution below.

I determine the number of days in the given month/year combination. Then I loop over the days and create the two required rows at the same time.

When done, the two rows are wrapped in a table and returned to the caller.

```
    <?php

    echo buildDate(12, 2017);

    function buildDate($month, $year)
    {
        // start with empty results
        $resultDate = "";
        $resultDays = "";
        // determine the number of days in the month
        $daysInMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $daysInMonth; $i++)
        {
            // create a cell for the day and for the date
            $resultDate .= "<td>".sprintf('%02d', $i)."</td>";
            $resultDays .= "<td>".date("l", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $i, $year))."</td>";
        }
        // return the result wrapped in a table
        return "<table>".PHP_EOL.
        "<tr>".$resultDate."</tr>".PHP_EOL.
        "<tr>".$resultDays."</tr>".PHP_EOL.
        "</table>";
    }

    ?>
```

phpfiddle link: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ffjm-hqsu

Comment: phpfiddle has some issues with the `sprintf('%02d', $i)`, replaced it with `$i` only

Answer (score 2):

Try this script:

```
// Day of month, e.g. 2014-12-14 if you need the table for december 2014
$date = time();

// Array containing the dates and weekdays
$days = array();
// loop to populate the array
for(
    $day = strtotime('midnight', strtotime(date('1 F Y', $date)));   /* first day of month */
    $day < strtotime(date('1 F Y', strtotime('next month', $date))); /* first day of next month */
    $day = strtotime('next day', $day)
){
    // insert current day into the array
    $days[date('d', $day)] = date('l', $day);
}

// print the row containing all day numbers
echo '<tr><td>'.implode('</td><td>', array_keys($days)).'</td></tr>';
// print the row containing all weekday names
echo '<tr><td>'.implode('</td><td>', $days).'</td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case `date('D', strtotime($date))` should work, but you need the date to be in format `yyyy-mm-dd`

I have done some tests so result:

```
for( $i=1; $i<= $num_of_days; $i++){
    $dates[]= str_pad($i,2,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $d = "2003-09-".$i;
    $days[] = date('D', strtotime($d));
}
```

Added another `tr` for days:

```
<tr>
<?php
foreach($days as $day){
    echo"<td>".$day."</td>";
}
?>
</tr>
```

Comment: only want date not the month and year in format. thats why i am getting date numbers. but stucked with the days.... :(

Comment: day always starts from monday in a month??, have you tested the code for different months???
http://codepad.viper-7.com/I53AYL

Comment: if you change the date in `(CAL_GREGORIAN, 12, 2012);` you need to change the date in `$d = "2003-09-".$i;` too. the code works very well.

Answer (score 1):

A DateTime method that builds an assoc array of date -> day.

The results for December 2015 look like this:

```
array(31) {
    [1] = string(7) "Tuesday"
    [2] = string(9) "Wednesday"
    [3] = string(8) "Thursday"
    [4] = string(6) "Friday"
    [5] = string(8) "Saturday"
    [6] = string(6) "Sunday"
    [7] = string(6) "Monday"
    [8] = string(7) "Tuesday"
    [9] = string(9) "Wednesday"
    [10] = string(8) "Thursday"
    [11] = string(6) "Friday"
    [12] = string(8) "Saturday"
    [13] = string(6) "Sunday"
    [14] = string(6) "Monday"
    [15] = string(7) "Tuesday"
    [16] = string(9) "Wednesday"
    [17] = string(8) "Thursday"
    [18] = string(6) "Friday"
    [19] = string(8) "Saturday"
    [20] = string(6) "Sunday"
    [21] = string(6) "Monday"
    [22] = string(7) "Tuesday"
    [23] = string(9) "Wednesday"
    [24] = string(8) "Thursday"
    [25] = string(6) "Friday"
    [26] = string(8) "Saturday"
    [27] = string(6) "Sunday"
    [28] = string(6) "Monday"
    [29] = string(7) "Tuesday"
    [30] = string(9) "Wednesday"
    [31] = string(8) "Thursday"
}
```

The full code to get your desired table:

```
<?php
// Get an array of days
$arrayDays = getDays(12, 2015);

// Function to get an array of days
function getDays($month, $year){
   // Start of Month
   $start = new DateTime("{$year}-{$month}-01");
   $month = $start->format('F');

   // Prepare results array
   $results = array();

   // While same month
   while($start->format('F') == $month){
      // Add to array
      $day              = $start->format('l');
      $date             = $start->format('j');
      $results[$date]   = $day;

      // Next Day
      $start->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
   }

   // Return results
   return $results;
}
?>


<!-- Output the Table -->
<table>
   <tr>
      <?php foreach (array_keys($arrayDays) as $someDate): ?>
         <td><?= $someDate; ?></td>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <?php foreach (array_values($arrayDays) as $someDate): ?>
         <td><?= $someDate; ?></td>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
   </tr>
</table>
```